# c++: call one function to get value and call another one to access the value

Tags: c++, function

I am a newbie in C++ and now I am writing some codes to practice. My question may be stupid and I have tried to search for answers but what I found are not in my case (I think so, probably I am so limited to my knowledge in C++..). Okay my problem is:

I have a main function which looks like:

```
#include "LoadMedia.h"
#include "Parser.h"
#include "Runner.h"
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char*argv[])
{
 LoadMedia script = LoadMedia(); // initialize an object of class LoadMedia
 script.loadScript("myscript.efa");  // loadScript is a function defined in class LoadMedia
 script.Parse(); // Parse is a function defined in class Parser, class LoadMedia is inheritaged from class Parser

 Runner tempRunner = Runner(); // initialize an object in class Runner
 tempRunner.Eval(); // Eval is a function defined in class Runner

 ...... // some other codes....

}
```

When calling the function

```
Parser::Parse()
```

I will get some values (int, string, double) and the function

```
Runner::Eval()
```

will need these values to do some evaluation.

I was wondering how to save the values obtained from Parse() somewhere where Eval() can also access these values easily...I am thinking whether I can use pointer or reference but I have no idea how to do it since I am so new in c++....Any ideas?

Comment: What is the return type of Parser::Parse()?

Comment: I think this is too vague to really be answerable. Some ideas as to what look into though are: `Parser::Parse()` could return another class or data structure which contains the values, and then you can pass that to `Runner::Eval()`. Alternatively, it might make more sense to pass the Script object to `Runner::Eval()`?

Comment: @gcandal many types, including int, double, string...would it be a good idea to use a vector or map to save the values?

Comment: @gladys0313 `std::vector` and `std::map` are homogeneous, i.e. they can't store different types. If you want to return values of different types, make a struct for them or use a `std::tuple`.

Comment: @notmyfriend thanks for your comments! What do you mean by "pass the script object to..."

Comment: @TartanLlama thanks for your comments!

Comment: @gladys0313 this kind of thing should be covered in your introductory text. If you don't have one, I'd recommend getting one from [this list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need to store these values you can take a look at the Parser.h to see which type is returned and store the same stype in your main.

If you don't care about storing values you can just do something like this :

```
tempRunner.Eval(script.Parse());
```

It will pass the returned values to Eval() automatically when parse has finished his job.

Comment: thanks for your comments! What if there are many return types? e.g. int, double, string....

Comment: Is it a templated fonction ?

Answer (score 0):

You can have 3 member variables int, string, double in LoadMedia class or Parser class (depending on design)
Inside `Parser :: Parse()`, fill these variables.
And then pass the Parser object to `Runner :: Eval()`

of course, this is just one way.